# How to create subpages with node.js using Amazon EC2 and heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, amazon-ec2

I'm a beginner programmer and pretty new to Node.js. 
I managed to setup a single static page by using AWS EC2 and Heroku, but I need help making other subpages. ie. mysite/blog or mysite/archive.

I started out with a simple web.js file I got from a sample node app which was:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.logger());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World!');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
```

---

All that said was Hello World so I created index.html and changed web.js to this.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var htmlfile = "index.html";
var app = express(express.logger());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(htmlfile).toString();
response.send(html);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
```

---

Now that serves index.html instead, but how do I get /blog or /archive to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add other routes to your code to handle specific URL formats. Make sure the more specific URLs are listed before the general route (/ or *)

```
// Handle request for blog
app.get('/blog', function(req, res){
  res.send('A list of blog posts should go here');
});

// Handle request for archive
app.get('/archive', function(req, res){
  res.send('Archive content should go here');
});

// Route for everything else.
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World');
});
```

I've got a more lengthy explanation about this here: http://hectorcorrea.com/#/blog/introduction-to-node-js/51